# Which introduction is preferred: "Myself [NAME]" or "I'm [NAME]"?

Tags: word-usage, american-english, indian-english

I want to know that in an interview, what is the correct way to introduce yourself?

Some use Myself ....(name), and some use I'm ___.

I'm confused about what is correct way?

Please guide me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no *one and only* "correct way".  I would not use "*myself*" as part of the introduction, though.

> Hello, **my name is** ...
>   Good morning/afternoon, **I am** ...

Comment: but in India i see that some people use Myself word to introduce

Comment: I am not sure what that might have to do with my answer.

Comment: @Garg's I'm from India as well and we follow the UK stand English, not US;

Secondly myself *name* sounds way too odd and cocky, if this were to be an interview the interviewee may take his decision then and there, its way better to simply say, Hello, I am ....

Comment: People don't introduce themselves with *myself* in standard British English  either.

Comment: @Invoker thanks for correcting me ............. actually i don't have much  knowledge about these things.